# How to convert 'not in' statement to join with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

How to get all records, except newest grouped by record_id?

Table:

```
attachments
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| record_id | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created   | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Source test rows in table attachments:

```
mysql> select * from attachments;
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | record_id | created    |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         1 | 2014-11-05 |
|  2 |         1 | 2014-11-04 |
|  3 |         1 | 2014-11-03 |
|  4 |         1 | 2014-11-02 |
|  5 |         2 | 2014-11-05 |
|  6 |         2 | 2014-11-04 |
|  7 |         2 | 2014-11-03 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

I created this query, but it's too slow with big tables:

```
SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE id NOT IN (
SELECT 
attachments.id
FROM attachments
GROUP BY attachments.record_id
ORDER BY attachments.`created` DESC
)
```

Result:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | record_id | created    |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  2 |         1 | 2014-11-04 |
|  3 |         1 | 2014-11-03 |
|  4 |         1 | 2014-11-02 |
|  6 |         2 | 2014-11-04 |
|  7 |         2 | 2014-11-03 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

My join query get other way round result, select's only newest grouped by record_id:

```
SELECT  old.*
FROM attachments `old`
INNER JOIN attachments `new` ON `new`.id = `old`.id
GROUP BY new.record_id
ORDER BY old.`created` DESC
```

Result:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | record_id | created    |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         1 | 2014-11-05 |
|  5 |         2 | 2014-11-05 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

Changing INNER to RIGHT or LEFT does not change output result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM attachments t1 
left outer join
(SELECT attachments.id
FROM attachments
GROUP BY attachments.record_id
ORDER BY attachments.`created` DESC) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24c3d/3)

Comment: This query is slowest than my first one.

Comment: Did you use index in your table?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
From attachments a
Where exists (Select *
              From attachments a2
              Where a.record_id = a2.record_id
              and   a.created < a2.created);
```

This query checks to make sure that there is other data with the same record id and a created date that is more recent. This will not work if you have two ids with the same record_id and created date as the two most recent records. This query will ignore them both.